# Can anyone help me to setup Solr with Tomcat in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, solr

I am new to Solr. I was trying to setup the Solr under Apache Tomcat 6.x in eclipse. i was able to import the solr.war in eclipse but when i try to run the project i got following error.

```
Mar 10, 2011 6:15:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SolrRequestFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3838)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Mar 10, 2011 6:15:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
```

Please can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

the tree structure of my project is as follow,

```
solr
+---.settings
+---build
¦   +---classes
+---conf
¦   +---xslt
+---data
¦   +---index
¦   +---spellchecker
+---src
+---WebContent
    +---admin
    ¦   +---replication
    +---META-INF
    +---WEB-INF
        +---lib
```

Please can anyone tell me what i am missing (any library file, CLASSPATH or any setting)

Libraries in my lib dir are as follow,

```
apache-solr-core-1.4.1.jar
apache-solr-dataimporthandler-1.4.1.jar
apache-solr-solrj-1.4.1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-csv-1.0-SNAPSHOT-r609327.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.5.jar
lucene-analyzers-2.9.3.jar
lucene-core-2.9.3.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.9.3.jar
lucene-memory-2.9.3.jar
lucene-misc-2.9.3.jar
lucene-queries-2.9.3.jar
lucene-snowball-2.9.3.jar
lucene-spellchecker-2.9.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.5.5.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
```

Please help. :(

Comment: When you said _my lib dir_, did you mean `solr-home/lib` or `Tomcat's lib` dir?

Comment: its in the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib dir. it is created in eclipse when you create a Dynamic web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solr installed on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, and this is how I have configured it:

#### Home Directory

The Solr base path is /usr/share/solr. In my case, this directory contains the folders bin, conf and data along with the solr.war. The WAR file holds all libraries.

#### solr.xml

I've created the file solr.xml in /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost. This file tells tomcat6 where to find the Solr home directory.

```
<Context docBase="/usr/share/solr/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

I'm not sure if you have done it already, but you need to tell tomcat6 where the Solr home directory can be found. After all, that's where the index/indicies will be kept. My setup might not be the cleanest (i struggled getting it to work too), but at least it works :-)