# Solr : SEVERE: Exception starting filter SolrRequestFilter

Tags: logging, solr, jar, tomcat6

I am able to get the **Tomcat** working , but **Solr** does not spring up.

I get the following exception with every **Tomcat** startup.

What is the problem here?

It does not specify if the problem is with SLF4J jars or anything else.

How am I going to debug this?

Has anyone come across a similar issue and can anyone throw some light on this?

Appreciate your response.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SolrRequestFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig6 reputa.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Comment: Is `solr/home` set properly?

Comment: Hi, yes the solr/home points to my top solr dir path

Comment: Double check your config according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270007/2892277

Comment: Hi again, the solr.xml seems to be pointing to the right solr.war file and solr/home to the right top level solr directory.

Comment: jetty seems to load solr properly with this command:  /usr/bin/java -jar start.jar. Why not tomcat6?

Comment: try to change to `/home/ora/sites/ora/parts/solr` (only guess).

Comment: I was just about to do this, but was wondering who you are :) many thanks!

Comment: I have deployed dozens of Solrs in production. But now sure we have to close this question as duplicate of question mentioned above due to StackOverflow policy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone help me to setup Solr with Tomcat in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260016/can-anyone-help-me-to-setup-solr-with-tomcat-in-eclipse)

Comment: Sure you can,  if the solution stated for the other works for me. But it looks like another issue, I'l post my questions until i get it right or find a suitable solution when after which you can decide to move the solution to the predecessor or retain this one.